# Why a const function and non-const is needed in a class?

Tags: c++, constants, sfml

I am learning SFML, and find it strange that there exists two get functions in the class resourceholder. But they are actually totally the same as each other.

My question is: Why is there two get functions?

the code is as followes:

```
template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
class ResourceHolder
{
    public:
        void                        load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename);

        template <typename Parameter>
        void                        load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename, const Parameter& secondParam);

        Resource&                   get(Identifier id);
        const Resource&             get(Identifier id) const;


    private:
        void                        insertResource(Identifier id, std::unique_ptr<Resource> resource);


    private:
        std::map<Identifier, std::unique_ptr<Resource>> mResourceMap;
};
```

Comment: It's similar to `std::vector::operator[]` BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same. One returns `Resource &` and the other returns `const Resource &`.

This is so that `get()` called on a const object returns a const reference, and `get()` called on a non-const object returns a non-const reference. Presumably the intent is to allow the caller to update the resource which this class is wrapping, but only on a non-const object.

Answer (score 1):

This is done to let you "channel" const-ness appropriately. The two functions give you two different things:

- The first function says that if you have a constant `ResourceHolder`, you can get a constant `Resource` reference from it
- The first function says that if you have a non-constant `ResourceHolder`, you can get a non-constant `Resource` reference from it

This lets your `ResourceHolder` be used in two contexts, without breaking the compile.

Note that having two different constants may be important in situations when you need two different implementations in different contexts. For example, non-`const` version could implement a get-or-create semantic, while the `const` version could throw an exception when the resource is missing.